# I've been struggling with CSS style related to create a 4-tier navigation bar. Please help me explain

Tags: css

According to a book, I have to use the CSS style like "#navigation ul li.sub:hover ul{display: block;}" to display a submenu. However, it isn't run as I expect, I have to code the other style like "#navigation ul li.sub:hover li{display: block;}", which leads to run. Please help me expalin this little change and give me your advice about creating a 2 or more-tier navigation bar!

```css
/* the styles for the elements */
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 3px solid #931420;
}
#body-background-color {
    background-color: #fffded;
}
/* the styles for the header */
#header-gradient{
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #f6bb73 0%, #f6bb73 30%, white 50%, #f6bb73 80%);
}
#header-border{
    border-bottom: 3px solid #931420;
    padding-top: 1.5em;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
}
header img {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
header h2{
    font-size: 170%;
    color: #800000;
}
header h3{
    font-size: 130%;
    font-style: italic;
}
.shadow{
    color:#800000;
    text-shadow: -2px -2px 4px yellow;
}

/* the style for navigation nemu */
#navigation ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#navigation ul li{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#navigation ul li a{
    display: block;
    width: 160px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #800000;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#navigation ul li.sub ul{
    position: absolute;
}
#navigation ul li.sub ul li{
    float: none;
    display: none;
    position: relative;
}
#navigation ul li.sub:hover li{
    display: block;
}
#navigation ul li.sub li.sub2 ul{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -100%;
    display: none;
}
#navigation ul li.sub li.sub2 ul li{
    position: relative;
}
#navigation ul li.sub li.sub2:hover ul{
    display: block;
}
#navigation ul li.sub li.sub2 li.sub3 ul{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
#navigation ul li.sub li.sub2 li.sub3:hover ul{
    display: block;
}
/* the styles for the main section */
main {
    clear: left;
}
main h2{
    font-size: 130%;
    color:#800000;
    padding-top: .5em;
    padding-bottom: .25em;
}
/* the styles for the aside */
aside{
    width: 215px;
    float:right;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
aside img{
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}
aside h3{
    font-size: 105%;
    padding-bottom: .25em;
}

/* the styles for the section */
section{
    width: 525px;
    float: right;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
section p{
    padding-bottom: .5em;
}
section q{
    padding-left: 2em;
    padding-right: 2em;
    font-style: italic;
}
section h1{
    font-size: 150%;
    padding-top: .5em;
    padding-bottom: .25em;
}
section article{
    border-top: 2px solid #800000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #800000;
}
section article h2{
    padding: 0;
}
section article h3{
    font-size: 105%;
    padding-bottom: .25em;
}
section article img{
    float: right;
    margin: .5em;
    border: 1px black;
}
section ul{
    padding-bottom: .25em;
    padding-left: 1.25em;
    list-style: circle
}
section li:hover, section li:focus{
    font-style: italic;
}
section li{
    padding-bottom: .35em;
}

/* the styles for the footer */
footer p{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    padding: 1em;
}
#footer-background{
    clear: both;
    border: 3px solid #931420;
    background-color: #931420; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>San Joaquin Valley Town Hall</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="body-background-color"> 
    <header>
     <div id="header-gradient">
     <div id="header-border">
     <img src="images/paisley-town-hall.jpg" alt="the logo of the town hall" height="100">
     <h2>San Joaquin Valley Town Hall</h2>
     <h3>Celebrating our <span class="shadow">75<sup>th</sup></span> Year</h3>
     </div>
     </div>
     
    </header>
    <nav id="navigation">      
    <ul>
     <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
     <li class="sub"><a href="#">About US</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Our history</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Board of Directors</a></li>
        <li class="sub2"><a href="#">Past Speakers</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="sub3"><a href="#">2015</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Mr A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mr B</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mrs C</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mrs D</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">2016</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2017</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Information</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="speakers/scott.html">Speakers</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Luncheons</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Ticket</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    <main>

    <section>
      <h2>Our Mission</h2>
      <p>San Joaquin Valley Town Hall is a non-profit organization that is run by an all-volunteer board of directors. Our mission is to bring nationally and internationally renowned, thought-provoking speakers who inform, educate, and entertain our audience! As one or our members told us&#58;</p>
      <p><q>Each year I give a ticket package to each of our family members. I think of it as the gift of knowledge...and that is priceless.</q></p>
      <h1>Speaker of the Month</h1>
      <article>
      <h2>Fossil Threads in the Web of Life</h2>
      <img src="images/sampson_dinosaur.jpg" alt="Sampson beside dinosaur" width="230" height="240">
      <h3>February<br>Scott Sampson</h3>
      <p>
      What's 75 million years old and brand spanking new? A teenage Utahceratops! Come to the Saroyan, armed with your best dinosaur roar, when Scott Sampson, Research Curator at the Utah Museum of Natural History, steps to the podium. Sampson's research has focused on the ecology and evolution of late Cretaceous dinosaurs and he has conducted fieldwork in a number of countries in Africa.</p>
      <p><a href="speakers/scott.html">Read more&#46;</a>&nbsp;<b><a href="media/sampson.swf" type="video/mp4">Or play video&#46;</a></b></p>
      </article>
      <h2>Our Ticket Packages</h2>
      <ul>
          <li>Season Package&#58; &#36;95</li>
          <li>Patron Package&#58; &#36;200</li>
          <li>Single Speaker&#58; &#36;25</li>
      </ul>
    </section>
    <aside>
     <h2>Guest speakers&#58;</h2>
     <h3>October<br><a href="speakers/toobin.html"> Jeffrey Toobin</a></h3>
     <img src="images/toobin75.jpg" alt="Toobin's portrait" width="70" height="70">
     <h3>November<br><a href="speakers/sorkin.html">Andrew Ross Sorkin</a></h3>
     <img src="images/sorkin75.jpg" alt="Sorkin's portrati" width="70" height="70">
     <h3>January<br><a href="speakers/chua.html">Amy Chua</a></h3>
     <img src="images/chua75.jpg" alt="Chua's portrait" width="70" height="70">
     <h3>February<br><a href="speakers/scott.html">Scott Sampson</a></h3>
     <img src="images/sampson75.jpg" alt="Sampon's portrait" width="70" height="70">
    </aside>  
    
    </main>
    
    <footer>
    
     <div id="footer-background">
     <p>&copy; 2018, San Joaquin Valley Town Hall, Fresno, CA 93755</p>
     </div>
     
    </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**strong text**

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `display: none` is set at `#navigation ul li.sub ul li`.
So I removed `display: none` from `#navigation ul li.sub ul li` and added `display: none` to `#navigation ul li.sub ul`.

Also I moved `display: block` from `#navigation ul li.sub:hover li` to `#navigation ul li.sub:hover ul`.

```css
/* the styles for the elements */
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 3px solid #931420;
}
#body-background-color {
    background-color: #fffded;
}
/* the styles for the header */
#header-gradient{
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #f6bb73 0%, #f6bb73 30%, white 50%, #f6bb73 80%);
}
#header-border{
    border-bottom: 3px solid #931420;
    padding-top: 1.5em;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
}
header img {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
header h2{
    font-size: 170%;
    color: #800000;
}
header h3{
    font-size: 130%;
    font-style: italic;
}
.shadow{
    color:#800000;
    text-shadow: -2px -2px 4px yellow;
}

/* the style for navigation nemu */
#navigation ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#navigation ul li{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#navigation ul li a{
    display: block;
    width: 160px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #800000;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#navigation ul li.sub ul{
    position: absolute;
}
/* ADD */
#navigation ul li.sub ul {
  display: none;
}
/*******/
#navigation ul li.sub ul li{
    float: none;
    /* display: none; */
    position: relative;
}
/*
#navigation ul li.sub:hover li{
    display: block;
}
*/
/* ADD */
#navigation ul li.sub:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
/*******/
#navigation ul li.sub li.sub2 ul{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -100%;
    display: none;
}
#navigation ul li.sub li.sub2 ul li{
    position: relative;
}
#navigation ul li.sub li.sub2:hover ul{
    display: block;
}
#navigation ul li.sub li.sub2 li.sub3 ul{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
#navigation ul li.sub li.sub2 li.sub3:hover ul{
    display: block;
}
/* the styles for the main section */
main {
    clear: left;
}
main h2{
    font-size: 130%;
    color:#800000;
    padding-top: .5em;
    padding-bottom: .25em;
}
/* the styles for the aside */
aside{
    width: 215px;
    float:right;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
aside img{
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}
aside h3{
    font-size: 105%;
    padding-bottom: .25em;
}

/* the styles for the section */
section{
    width: 525px;
    float: right;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
section p{
    padding-bottom: .5em;
}
section q{
    padding-left: 2em;
    padding-right: 2em;
    font-style: italic;
}
section h1{
    font-size: 150%;
    padding-top: .5em;
    padding-bottom: .25em;
}
section article{
    border-top: 2px solid #800000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #800000;
}
section article h2{
    padding: 0;
}
section article h3{
    font-size: 105%;
    padding-bottom: .25em;
}
section article img{
    float: right;
    margin: .5em;
    border: 1px black;
}
section ul{
    padding-bottom: .25em;
    padding-left: 1.25em;
    list-style: circle
}
section li:hover, section li:focus{
    font-style: italic;
}
section li{
    padding-bottom: .35em;
}

/* the styles for the footer */
footer p{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    padding: 1em;
}
#footer-background{
    clear: both;
    border: 3px solid #931420;
    background-color: #931420; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>San Joaquin Valley Town Hall</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="body-background-color"> 
    <header>
     <div id="header-gradient">
     <div id="header-border">
     <img src="images/paisley-town-hall.jpg" alt="the logo of the town hall" height="100">
     <h2>San Joaquin Valley Town Hall</h2>
     <h3>Celebrating our <span class="shadow">75<sup>th</sup></span> Year</h3>
     </div>
     </div>
     
    </header>
    <nav id="navigation">      
    <ul>
     <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
     <li class="sub"><a href="#">About US</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Our history</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Board of Directors</a></li>
        <li class="sub2"><a href="#">Past Speakers</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="sub3"><a href="#">2015</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Mr A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mr B</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mrs C</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mrs D</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">2016</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2017</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Information</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="speakers/scott.html">Speakers</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Luncheons</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Ticket</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    <main>

    <section>
      <h2>Our Mission</h2>
      <p>San Joaquin Valley Town Hall is a non-profit organization that is run by an all-volunteer board of directors. Our mission is to bring nationally and internationally renowned, thought-provoking speakers who inform, educate, and entertain our audience! As one or our members told us&#58;</p>
      <p><q>Each year I give a ticket package to each of our family members. I think of it as the gift of knowledge...and that is priceless.</q></p>
      <h1>Speaker of the Month</h1>
      <article>
      <h2>Fossil Threads in the Web of Life</h2>
      <img src="images/sampson_dinosaur.jpg" alt="Sampson beside dinosaur" width="230" height="240">
      <h3>February<br>Scott Sampson</h3>
      <p>
      What's 75 million years old and brand spanking new? A teenage Utahceratops! Come to the Saroyan, armed with your best dinosaur roar, when Scott Sampson, Research Curator at the Utah Museum of Natural History, steps to the podium. Sampson's research has focused on the ecology and evolution of late Cretaceous dinosaurs and he has conducted fieldwork in a number of countries in Africa.</p>
      <p><a href="speakers/scott.html">Read more&#46;</a>&nbsp;<b><a href="media/sampson.swf" type="video/mp4">Or play video&#46;</a></b></p>
      </article>
      <h2>Our Ticket Packages</h2>
      <ul>
          <li>Season Package&#58; &#36;95</li>
          <li>Patron Package&#58; &#36;200</li>
          <li>Single Speaker&#58; &#36;25</li>
      </ul>
    </section>
    <aside>
     <h2>Guest speakers&#58;</h2>
     <h3>October<br><a href="speakers/toobin.html"> Jeffrey Toobin</a></h3>
     <img src="images/toobin75.jpg" alt="Toobin's portrait" width="70" height="70">
     <h3>November<br><a href="speakers/sorkin.html">Andrew Ross Sorkin</a></h3>
     <img src="images/sorkin75.jpg" alt="Sorkin's portrati" width="70" height="70">
     <h3>January<br><a href="speakers/chua.html">Amy Chua</a></h3>
     <img src="images/chua75.jpg" alt="Chua's portrait" width="70" height="70">
     <h3>February<br><a href="speakers/scott.html">Scott Sampson</a></h3>
     <img src="images/sampson75.jpg" alt="Sampon's portrait" width="70" height="70">
    </aside>  
    
    </main>
    
    <footer>
    
     <div id="footer-background">
     <p>&copy; 2018, San Joaquin Valley Town Hall, Fresno, CA 93755</p>
     </div>
     
    </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```